# Swift 4 Function parameter var

Tags: swift, function

I am very new to Swift. I am trying to create func...

```
func circlesDisabledCondition(playerScoreValue: var) {

    if playerScoreValue < 1 {
        circle1.isEnabled = false
    }
    if playerScoreValue < 5 {
        circle5.isEnabled = false
    }
    if playerScoreValue < 50 {
        circle50.isEnabled = false
    }
    if playerScoreValue < 100 {
        circle100.isEnabled = false
    }
    else {
        circlesEnabled()
    }
}
```

Of course (playerScoreValue: var) doesn't work, I have no idea how can I write it down.

Calling func example (wrong it is just example that I am looking for something like that...)

```
 circlesDisabledCondition(playerScoreValue: player2ScoreValue)
```

I am looking for this output.

```
if player2ScoreValue < 1 {
        circle1.isEnabled = false
    }
    if player2ScoreValue < 5 {
        circle5.isEnabled = false
    }
    if player2ScoreValue < 50 {
        circle50.isEnabled = false
    }
    if player2ScoreValue < 100 {
        circle100.isEnabled = false
    }
    else {
        circlesEnabled()
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: What is `playerScoreValue`? is it an int? float? double? whatever it is, you can use that in place of var in your function.

Comment: You need define var type. For example  `circlesDisabledCondition(playerScoreValue: Int)`

Comment: playerScoreValue is Int. I am not looking for (playerScoreValue: Int) I want to replace playerScoreValue with for example player2ScoreValue

Comment: Why not? Are you looking for `playerScoreValue: Any`? if you dont specify type, compiler wont know what `playerScoreValue < 1` means.

Comment: Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `var` with whatever type your `playerScoreValue` is. If it's an integer, use `Int`, if it's a float, use `float` etc.

You can call your function with any variable or value as long as it's of the specified type.